# how to connect multiple identical Links from different components?

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, router

i am trying to connect this route :

```
<Route path={`/movie/:id/`} exact component={MovieDetail} />
```

with:

```
 <Link to={`movie/${i.id}`}>
          <MovieCard key={i.id} data_info={i} />
        </Link>
```

and second comming from different component as:

```
{object2.map((i) => (
            <Link to={`movie/${i.id}`}>
              <MovieCard data_info={i} />
            </Link>
          ))}
```

first one works: http://localhost:3000/movie/20526
, second starts stacking as :
http://localhost:3000/movie/movie/20526

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that your `Link` component goes relatively to your current route to `movie/:id`, you could tell it to the new URL absolutely by putting a `/` before your route.
It would look like this:

```js
<Link to={`/movie/${i.id}`}>
  <MovieCard key={i.id} data_info={i} />
</Link>
```